# jquery ajax request fails with error in chrome (with async: false), but works in FF

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, jquery, xmlhttprequest

Trying to build what should be a simple AJAX request with jQuery.  Here's the coffeescript:

```
$('#ad_id_string').blur(function() {
    var self, idString, adURL;
    self = $(this);
    if (self.val() != "") {
      idString = self.val();
      adURL = "/advertisements/" + idString;
      $.ajax({
        url: adURL,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        data: "",
        async: false,
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
          console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          console.log("Failed - " + textStatus + " : " + errorThrown);
        }
      });
    }
});
```

Firefox executes the request with no problem, and the JSON is returned as expected.  However, Chrome refuses to even send the request.  Instead, it gives this error: `NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101`

I've tried setting `async:true` instead of `false`, as well as removing the `async` parameter all together.  That just causes chrome to fail the request before sending without an error of any kind.  My Q/A folks will be testing this in Chrome or Safari, so it needs to work in those browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this had something to do with my version of Chrome (23.0.1271.97), and the url in question.  I'm using Rails, so I was hitting `http://localhost:3000`, and Chrome has issues passing AJAX requests with port numbers.